# Ignore Null Values When Serializing JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Is it possible to serialize an object to JSON but only those properties with data?

For example:

```
public class Employee
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
   public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "supervisor")]
   public string Supervisor { get; set; }
}

var employee = new Employee { Name = "John Doe", EmployeeId = 5, Supervisor = "Jane Smith" };

var boss = new Employee { Name = "Jane Smith", EmployeeId = 1 };
```

The employee object will be serialized as:

```
 { "id":"5", "name":"John Doe", "supervisor":"Jane Smith" }
```

The boss object will be serialized as:

```
 { "id":"1", "name":"Jane Smith" }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could do something like this on your JSON properties:

```
[JsonProperty("property_name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
```

Alternatively you can ignore null values when you serialize.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Comment: For anyone who might struggle to get this to work with VB.NET the syntax is as follows **JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee, Formatting.Indented, New JsonSerializerSettings With {.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore})** or for the object decoration declaration use **<JsonPropertyAttribute("Presets", DefaultValueHandling:=NullValueHandling.Ignore)>**